# How can I sort for character and number in c?

Tags: c, list, data-structures, queue

I'm working with queque and struct. I want to use enqueue function and struct variables. Then I sort list according to their character and number. For example :

I have 3 character:

1- A

2- C

3- G

C is the most important value. C is the first element of list always. After C, G is important and then A.

And also numbers are sorted from little to big.

My struct sholud see :

```
struct n{
    char i;
    int a;
    struct n *next;
}
```

and I must use enqueue function. It looks like :

```
void enqueue (char i,int a);
```

And my main like this :

```
enqueue(C,5);
enqueue(C,1);
enqueue(A,0);
enqueue(G,7);
enqueue(A,5);
enqueue(G,3);
```

My output like this:

```
C1 C5 G3 G7 A0 A5
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: How are the letters ranked? Is it only C, G, and A with C < G < A? Or is there a more elaborate ranking?

Comment: C > G > A @templatetypedef

Comment: Is `enqueue` a member function on `n`? Or is it defined somewhere else?

Comment: I mean c is the important. So maybe C's number is smaller than G or A ,  but still it is the first on the list .@templatetypedef

Comment: enqueue has 2 paramaters char and int. and it doesn't defined anywhere @templatetypedef

Comment: The short of it, pairs appear in C G A order, with each subsequence (the "C's, if you will) sorted by ascending digits). And there is no output in your code (for that matter there is barely *code*). What have you done so far?

Comment: @WhozCraig  because i haven't still started for writing :/ I need some advice

Comment: Oh, well in that case, build yourself [**one of these**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Ok but i ask you one question. Can i sort both priority character and number together ??@WhozCraig

Comment: The short of it is no, they're independent orderings. You *may* be able to  cheat and do some value-bit-twiddling  by storing the char value in the high byte of a larger scaler and the char index in the low-end, but honestly, it wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: It is oo hard for me :/ Now , i must start to build priority sort codes @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0):

I think the order in which you stated the character priorities is in-congruent to your statement. Regardless, why are you using a queue to store something which has non FIFO order? What you are looking for is a linked list.

Here is how I would go about thinking about this...

You have two types of lists, one is a set of chars ordered by priority (you know the order before hand - in our case C > G > A). So start off with three lists one for each char, where each list points to another list of numbers.

```
# Initially you will have:
HEAD --> [ C: [] ] --> [ G: [] ] --> [ A: [] ] --> NULL
enqueue(C,5);
HEAD --> [ C: [5] ] --> [ G: [] ] --> [ A: [] ] --> NULL
enqueue(C,1);
HEAD --> [ C: [1, 5] ] --> [ G: [] ] --> [ A: [] ] --> NULL
enqueue(A,0);
HEAD --> [ C: [1, 5] ] --> [ G: [] ] --> [ A: [0] ] --> NULL
enqueue(G,7);
HEAD --> [ C: [1, 5] ] --> [ G: [7] ] --> [ A: [0] ] --> NULL
enqueue(A,5);
HEAD --> [ C: [1, 5] ] --> [ G: [7] ] --> [ A: [0, 5] ] --> NULL
enqueue(G,3);
HEAD --> [ C: [1, 5] ] --> [ G: [3, 7] ] --> [ A: [0, 5] ] --> NULL
```

You can also implement a sort function which first sorts by numbers:

```
# Unsorted list
stack -> {c,5} -> {c,1} -> {a,0} -> {g,7} -> {a,5} -> {g,3} -> NULL

# Sort by numbers
stack -> {a,0} -> {c,1} -> {g,3} -> {c,5} -> {a,5} -> {g,7} -> NULL

# sort by your specific letter order, you would need to check 
# c > g > a etc
stack -> {c,1} -> {c,5} -> {g,3} -> {g,7} -> {a,0} -> {a,5} -> NULL
```

Comment: Queues with an order are something very common: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: of course! I had (wrongly?) assumed this was a question asking to implement a the enqueue (essentially a prioQ), and was just trying to nudge the op in that direction without actually pointing to source :)

Comment: @sabhiram I must use enqueue for this sorting

Comment: So you mean as the items are en-queued onto the struct, they should be placed in the correct order? Or can they be in any order, and are resolved to the right order when printed? Which is it? One is asking: how to implement enqueue so that they are added in order, the other is asking how to sort a linked list of {char, int} nodes.

Comment: @sabhiram  They ae sorted correctly and then printed .i don't know how to sort char and int are in a node :/

Comment: See edit, you can just sort first by the numbers - and then sort them in whatever letter order you want. I still think its better to have `enqueue()` sort them on insertion, but obviously you cant change that if you cannot implement your own `enqueue()`